# xml - XSLT How to match a node using the index of another node

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been asked to see if there is a way to match a given node based on the index of a named node? Here's an example:

`<RecordSets>
    <RecordSet RecordSetId="Events">
        <Columns>
            <Col Name="a" Type="Free" />
            <Col Name="b" Type="Free" />
            <Col Name="c" Type="Free" />
            <Col Name="d" Type="Free" />
            <Col Name="e" Type="Free" />
        </Columns>
        <Rows>

            <Row>
                <Col>1</Col>
                <Col>2</Col>
                <Col>3</Col>
                <Col>4</Col>
                <Col>5</Col>
            </Row>

            <Row>
                <Col/>
                <Col/>
                <Col/>
                <Col/>
                <Col />
            </Row>

        </Rows>
    </RecordSet>
</RecordSets>`

So in this case I want to be able to select the index of say `<Col Name="e" Type="Free" />` and use that index to match a template to `<Col>5</Col>`

I'm really struggling to achieve this. The best I've managed to come up with so far is:

`<xsl:template match="Col[position() = last()" mode="RSLCell">`

Which 'works' given my simplified example, but the position which needs to be selected won't always be the last one. Any ideas greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT** some clarification: I have a template with the following format. Due to business constraints I can only really modify the internals of the template. We are using XSLT v1.

```
 <xsl:template match="Col[position() = last()]">    
    <!-- This will be a serialized CaseEventAction collection, get a new document and match the events-->
    <xsl:variable name="document" select="extensions:XmlDataItemValueAsNodeSet(text())"/>       
    <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$document/applyAnotherTemplate" /> 
    </td>
```

As you can see, this only works by virtue of the item in question being in the last() position. This is no longer the case and we now need to match the `<col>` tag with the same number/index at the `<col Name="e"... />` tag.

Comment: Are you trying to pick the value in a specific column (by name) only? If yes, from which row/s? Please post the expected output of the (entire) transformation.

Comment: I'm trying to match a template to the 5th (<Col>5</Col>) entry in <Row>; using the index of <Col Name="e" Type="Free" />. The template formats the content of <col> before applying another template to it. Sorry if I'm not being very clear. My xsl exposure is fairly minimal.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question - which is not about XSLT, but about your overall purpose. What is being given here, and what is the expected result? -- Also please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Thanks; I've added to the original post. Hope that clears things up :)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use a positional predicate in the form of `<xsl:template match="Row/Col[position() = count(/RecordsSets/RecordSet[@RecordSetId = 'Events']/Columns/Col[@Name = 'e']/preceding-sibling::Col) + 1]"/>`.